# 1 domain two separate applications

Tags: iis-6, dns, isapi-rewrite, subdirectory

- http://www.one.com

  and

  - http://www.one.com/uk

www.one.com is the main site, but there is a UK version of this site which ideally needs to be in a subdirectory (/uk).

How do set IIS up to allow me to have multiple sites under one domain?

Or can I have two separate sites and use ISAPI_rewrite to point www.one.com/uk to read from another site but keep the url www.one.com/uk?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just [setup a virtual directory](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/5adfcce1-030d-45b8-997c-bdbfa08ea459.mspx) that points at the second application?  Assuming you are using asp.net, you'd have to make sure there was no overlap in the web.config files (you may have to remove/add some elements) but a virtual directory would be a simple solution I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a virtual "/uk" directory. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138

You can do it with ISAPI_Rewrite with the proxy if you needed to use multiple domains but I would recommend if you had to use multiple domains doing it the easy way by making the second site : uk.one.com using host headers. http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/

Answer (score 0):

You could just set up a virtual directory called "uk" inside the main site for "www.one.com", and place the UK version of the application inside it. You'll need to make sure that the application inside it either uses relative links (to make sure it does not stray out into the main application), or it's absolute links include the /uk/ prefix.

Alternatively, have you considered using two hostnames? E.g.,  www.one.com for global/ US/ non-UK, and uk.one.com for the UK site?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could set up subdomain like uk.one.com and redirect user there if he is from uk. It's easier.